# How to let user download a file after he confirms his ID number on drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have over a thousend reports on a google drive folder, each one named after the ID number of the person who was evaluated.
I want to share them a single link to some kind of google form that asks them to sign their own ID number and then lets them to download their specific PDF file, without having access to other file in the folder.
Is there a way to do this on google drive?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `I want to share a link that asks some user to sign its ID number and then let him download an specific PDF file stored on a google drive foder.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And also, can you provide the detail goal you expect?

Comment: What about if instead of asking for the ID you share the file only with specific users ?

Comment: @Tanaike, It's my english the problem, sorry.
I have over a thousend reports, I need to deliver each student his own unique report, but I can't do it manually.
I want to share a link to some page  (som likeething a google form) that asks the student to submit his ID, and uses it to sarch the report on the drive and lets the student to download it.
Email is not an option.

Comment: @ziganotschka, this is nt an option since I have over a thousend reports and I might get even more.

Comment: You could write a script that returns the user on Form Submit the download link to his specific file, but implies that you have somewhere a table that specifies which specific PDF file id is assigned to which specific user ID.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [ziganotschka's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11599789/ziganotschka) approach.

I created a google sheets document with two macros with triggers.

The first macro scans the current folder and lists every element on it with the name of the document and the download link. This macro is auto-treiggered every 10 minutes.

The second macro has onFormSubmit tregger and recives the answers of the form and contrasts them with the PDFs name (since all the PDF are conviniently named). when user is found, the macro sends the download link to the email of the user who filled the form.

At the end, I just have to share the form's link with the students